# .net core Fullcalendar get data by giving month

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We are using fullcalendar with .net core- ef core. We are getting all the event data by passing it to fullcalendar.That means a lot of event.Then It creates event calendar with theese data default by this month. What I want is make it lazy. When getting data, it would returns only events giving month.

in c#

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(E_Model model){
     var list = _Service.GetEvents().ToList();
   }
```

in js ajax calling file

```
function GetEvents() {
  
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/calHome/GetEvents",
            data: { model: data },
            success: function (data) {
                calender.style.display = 'block';          
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {                       
                    events.push({
                        id: v.id,
                        title: v.name,
                        description: v.description,      
              //i got start and end moment
             start: moment(v.start),
                    end: v.end != null ? moment(v.end) : null,});
        })
        GenerateCalender(events);

}
```

Generate calendar

```
function GenerateCalender(events) {
    $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
    $('#calender').fullCalendar({
        contentHeight: 800,
        firstDay: 1,
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
 eventLimit: true,
        events: events,
}
```

ajax GetEvents calls GetEvents in controller it returns json then GetEvents in ajax calls genaretecalendar. When Calling the GetEvents metod in aja.
I want to make it when I press the prev or next button, it will give the month to controller and get data by month. I tryed to listen prev event like

```
$('.fc-prev-button').one('click',function (e) {
                console.log('prev, do something');
            });
```

**NEW**

```
 events: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/GetEvents",
            data: function () { // a function that returns an object
                return {
                     
                };
            }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetEvents(FiltModel model)
                               //model includes string start, end
```

Comment: Also how can I listen when prev or next button clicked

Comment: do you have any suggest @ADyson

Comment: Have you spent any time looking at the documentation? fullCalendar makes this quite easy actually - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed  and  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function (these are two different approaches to achieve the result you want)

Comment: Once you follow this guidance you just also need to make sure your server receives the dates being sent from the calendar and uses them in the database query

Comment: There is dynamic data options here but I think theese are not my solution. How can I listen which mont we are looking and pass it to controller

Comment: You do that by using the dynamic data options. They automatically provide the current date range. Did you not understand the documentation?

Comment: Well this time it calls json every page changed. but how can I give the month to controller. I added new code

Comment: fullCalendar automatically sends a start and end date to the controller when it runs the request. The documentation explains that - was it not clear, somehow?? And you should be able to see it happening in your network tool in your browser too. So you don't need to do anything for that in the JavaScript, you just need to configure your controller to receive the start and end date parameters.

Comment: Well master your answers makes me amusing, so sarcastic :) In controller we are getting a model and I added thees parameters can you check out. start and end comes null

Comment: Did you try adding them to the model class instead of being separate parameters? P.S. Sorry if you think I'm being sarcastic or whatever, but I do get a bit frustrated when people ask me questions that are already answered in the documentation. Wouldn't you feel the same way?

Comment: And also what is in the `FiltModel` class anyway? Nothing else is being sent to your server in this request, so what is its purpose here. Also in ASP.NET Core if I'm not mistaken, you have to write `[FromBody] FiltModel model` if you want to read a property from the POST body. You'd have to check the browser's network tool to see if the start/end parameters are actually being sent in the request body or on the querystring. I normally use a GET request for fetching events, so I don't know what fullCalendar will do with a POST. So actually you _could_ just use GET for this - it would be simpler.

Comment: Master don't be get frustrated , sarcasm some times not a bad thing and i enjoyed to talk with you, thank you for that and your labors. I'm gona make it

Comment: And also FiltModel means filter model for calendar, i will make it get request

Comment: ok well if you need to pass extra data like your filter model, you will need to use an extra setting - as described in the "Dynamic data parameter" section of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed .

Comment: YEs finally made it with your help, thank you much . Have a good day master

Comment: Can you make it answer and I accept it ?

Comment: Well I would like to, but I don't actually know for sure which version of your code was the final version which worked?

Comment: I added start and end to my filtmodel, also calling getevents dynamic. The down below. Thank you again

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer below - do you think that covers everything I need to say?

Comment: Yes It covers, its a good answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use the [events as JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) pattern described in the fullCalendar documentation.

Essentially it works like this: if you tell fullCalendar the URL of your controller action, it will automatically make a new request to the server whenever the date range changes in the calendar (and it does not already have downloaded events for that date range). It will also automatically append "start" and "end" date parameters to the request - so then all your server has to do is read those parameters and use them in your database query to filter the results being returned to the calendar. You can also, optionally, append other relevant data to the request as well - such as your other filter options.

So in your case you would end up with code something like this:

JavaScript - fullCalendar events configuration:

```
events: {
  type: "POST",
  url: "/home/GetEvents",
  data: function () { // a function that returns an object
  return {
    //your filter object goes here
  };
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetEvents(FiltModel model) {
   //...where the FiltModel class includes start and end parameters - ideally these should be DateTime objects, not strings.

   //... then, query the database using the filter options in the model, and return JSON in the format required by fullCalendar
}
```