# Fullcalender json feeds

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to make dynamic calendarevents. It calls controller function when date/month changes. My controller filters value which comes from ajax call(start, end). So thees are my functions

```
  events: function (start, end, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/GetData",
                        dataType: 'json',
//this automaticly adds Start and End param to controller. Datetime
                        data: {
                             
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, type, exception) { alert("Error: " + exception); },
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
//Response works fine, it return all objects what I  need.
                        }
                        });
                      },
```

So basicly this function calls GetData json form Home controller with start and end parameter in every month changes. Also I can log this data it comes. but this events are not filled. console log says  in `eventrender`

```
  eventRender: function (event, element) {

                console.log("event");
                console.log(event);
--
event
undefined
```

It doesn't fill events but also I'm using it with same way in other page but it works.

```
events: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/GetEvents",
            data: function () { // a function that returns an object
               
                return {
                   
                };
            }
        },
```

What just I need to add this to fill events. Thank you

Also I added evetnSoucers but its same

```
 eventSources: [

                   
                    {
                       
                        url: "/Home/GetData",
                        method: 'POST',
                        
                        failure: function () {
                            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        }, success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            myfunc(response);
                        }
                       
                    }

                ],
```

**NEW2**

This code below call controller with start, end parameter and returns expected value. I can call  another function with response value also I can console.log this reponse values. When I add callback to set them my events it says callback is not a function

```
 events: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/home/GetData",
                    data: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { // a function that returns an object

                        return {
                            // dynamic_value: Math.random()
                        };
                    }, success: function (response) {
                       
                        callback(response);
                        console.log("response");
                        console.log(response);
                        some_func(response);
                        
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Anyone to help me with tihs

Comment: You had this working a few days ago (in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106933/net-core-fullcalendar-get-data-by-giving-month) ... what's changed? Why did you mess with it?

Comment: Anyway see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function - it's `function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }` instead of `function( start, end, callback ) { }` and also you need to actually use `callback` to return the events to fullcalendar - e.g. `success: function (response) {
                            callback(response); }`. The documentation both describes and shows the use of it.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned it works fine with your answer. I'm using this fullcalendar in 4 page with same way. 3 of 4 works fine but one of them just not showing events.I can get start end values in every month changes.I added calback(response) method in success. console says callback is not a function

Comment: You also need to make the other change I described as well. Read my comment again

Comment: I changed the code as your said but it says now Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined in moment.js. When I searched it happens because start and end param. THe new code I changed added. not it says start undefined

Comment: `this.start = moment(event.start).format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
                this.end = moment(event.end).format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');` this makes no sense. What is `this` supposed to be in this context? And what is `event` supposed to be? Where do they come from?? And it's bad to send data in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, it's ambiguous for the server (e.g. 01/03/2020 could be seen 2 different ways). And your format tokens are wrong anyway - check the momentJS docs! Oh and start and end are already moments, you don't need to parse them again. It would make more sense like this:

Comment: `var startStr = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endStr = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/home/GetData",
                    data: {
                        start: startStr,
                        end: endStr
                    },`

Comment: (But still I don't understand why you can't just write `events: {
  type: "POST",
  url: "/home/GetEvents",...` like you did for the other 3 pages. If it somehow didn't work on one of the pages maybe you should focus on why that is, and fix it, rather than making workarounds??)

Comment: Well you are right and because of this i added another code this just start:start, end:end but this way it gives another error

Comment: The point is i got reponse expected but can't set response values.

Comment: Sorry but with `data: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { ` you have got yourself 100% percent confused between the two different methods of setting up an event feed (JSON feed and custom function). I don't even know how to start untangling it for you. You seem to just be guessing wildly.

Comment: What does "i got reponse expected but can't set response values" mean exactly? Please be clear and precise. I cannot infer your exact problem from a vague description.

Comment: Let's go back to when you tried to use `events: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/GetEvents",` in this page. How **exactly** does this fail? Do you get some errors?

Comment: I got error in the simplest event json feed. fullcalendar.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at P (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at O (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at V (fullcalendar.min.js:6)

Comment: eventRender: function (event, element) {

                    console.log("event");
                    console.log(event);   is not working. data not comes there

Comment: From that error it seems maybe some of the event data is missing a start and/or end property. Did you check the JSON that's being generated? Use the browser's network tool to examine the response to the AJAX request.

Comment: I changed the some of property name and surprisingly it starts showing events. Interesting ,really

Comment: What do you mean? Which property names did you have to change on your events? If you don't use the property names that fullCalendar expects then it can't process the events. It can't guess which fields you are wanting to use, the names must match the fullCalendar documentation exactly.

Comment: Yes it has to match  fullCalendar documentation exactly.I just changed title property with same as fullcalendar and it works

Comment: Ok good. That's not really very surprising though - if you don't include a required field then it's not going to work. The documentation clearly mentions what all the field names are and which ones are required.

Comment: yes it was i just missed it

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** as noted by @ADyson in the comments, I bypassed the FullCalendar version assuming you are using the last version. I updated the signature to the v3 one, even so you are wrong with the way you are using it.

I think you are getting stuck because you are missunderstanding the [events (as a fuction)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function). If you check the documentation you will see that the signature for the events function is:

```js
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }
```

where:

- `start` and `end` are Moments denoting the range the calendar needs events for.
- `timezone` is a string/boolean describing the calendar’s current timezone..
- `callback` is a function that must be called when the custom event function has generated its events.

So, if you are using AJAX,  you could do it in this way:

```js
{
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    const data = {
      start: start,
      end: end
      // ...
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'url',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
      .done(function(res) {
        if (res.error) {
          // Show error logic
          // ...
        } else {
          const events = res.data.events;
          callback(events);
        }
      })
      .fail(function(res){
        // Show error logic
        // ...
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The way you make your request may vary, but in essence, the main thing is to call `callback()` when everything went fine or <strike>`failureCallback()` when something went wrong</strike> handle the error if exists. Thus you'll be able to view the events through the `eventRender` function if you need to customize your events.

If you have filters or similar stuff (or simply need to refresh the events) you could do it by calling [`.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents). Remember to manage the filtering data on the `events: function (...) {}`. Calling to this function will call the `events` function to fetch and render the events.

Comment: Your overall point is correct, but as per the OP's [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106933/net-core-fullcalendar-get-data-by-giving-month) they are actually using fullCalendar 3. Their function signature attempt was wrong too, but you need to update your answer to work with fullCalendar 3.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for the observation, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i'm sure it will help others